# install a python library, specifically pycurl, on my heroku box (Rails application)

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I built this rails application locally and deployed it via Heroku. There is this important python script I rely on that heavily uses the pycurl library. My script is able to run locally because I was able to easily download and install pycurl on my local machine. The problem is pycurl is not installed remotely on Heroku, and I cannot seem to figure out how to install pycurl so that Heroku can run my python script. I downloaded setuptools, as well as the pycurl tar file in my rails app and tried to ssh into heroku and run something like python setyp.py install, or pip install pycurl, however, none of these commands will run because I do not and cannot have write access to this directory: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ on heroku (you also cannot run these commands as root because Heroku will not allow you too). After trying everything, it seems like I should follow these instructions from Heroku, which gets printed to my terminal after running python setup.py install:

".....If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable."

I am not sure how to go about this. Any help wold be much appreciated.

Also, I have come across a few stack overflow posts but none have been able to help so far. Let me know if you need any more info from me.

TL;DR - Installing a python module/library on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

add a requirements.txt file to your python deployment. 
Write your python dependencies in it (add any other dependencies you have not only pycurl).
check [this doc from heroku guys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)

I use pycurl on my heroku app and have found no problem uploading to heroku..

> ```
>   Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
>    Downloading/unpacking pycurl==7.19.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
>      Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
>        Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)  
>
>   Installing collected packages: pycurl
>      Running setup.py install for pycurl
>        Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)
>        building 'pycurl' extension
>        gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c src/pycurl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o
>        src/pycurl.c: In function ‘do_multi_info_read’:
>        src/pycurl.c:2843: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
>        src/pycurl.c: In function ‘multi_socket_callback’:
>        src/pycurl.c:2355: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_string’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to char * for this info
>        In function ‘util_curl_unsetopt’,
>            inlined from ‘do_curl_unsetopt’ at src/pycurl.c:1551:
>        src/pycurl.c:1476: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_CURLSH’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a CURLSH* argument for this option
>        gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pycurl.o -lcurl -lidn -lssl -lcrypto -llber -lldap -lrt -lgssapi_krb5 -lgssapi_krb5 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycurl.so /usr/lib/libcurl.a
>
>  Successfully installed pycurl
> ```

Comment: I can't include a requirements.txt file because I'm running Ruby on Rails, not Django.....

Comment: requirements.txt is read by pip when found, but that implies that python is the language of choice.. as long as i know, you cannot mix different languages on same app.. any chance to deploy two separate apps that talk with each other? otherwise, you will need a rails version of pycurl.. (if it exists)